# What type of cable goes into the display port?

Tags: display, displayport

My PC has a display port and so does my monitor, the shape of these ports look the same. So I decided to look up online for some display port cable, but the search results in like 80% of all commercial websites show a Display port to HDMI converter cable or Display port to VGA converter cable. Is there a  cable I can use to hook the display port on my PC to the display port on the monitor?

[image]

In short, i need a Display Port to Display port cable

Comment: Did you want tp connect two pc's together via a display port cable (not possible?) or did you mistype "display port on my pc to the display port on my monitor" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your search is for DP male to DP female

[image]

There's no such thing. Video cables are male > male [unless, rarely, an extension]

Just search "displayport cable" & you'll find hundreds of them.

[image]

Comment: my monitor has a flicker on black backgrounds, i read from an online source switching from VGA to either DVI or DP will fix the issue, are they correct?

Comment: it depends on what's actually causing the flicker, but yes, VGA is a seriously out of date protocol. Anything should be better than that.

Comment: Okay thanks for that information, what about the refresh rate?, is it monitor dependent or interface cable some who affects it

Comment: white backgrounds do not flicker, its only black backgrounds

Comment: HDMI/DVI/DisplayPort all support everything you need. If you want to do something extreme (very large resolutions or very large refresh rates) then you might need to look for beefier cables, but for 99% of consumer level stuff the regular cables will be enough.

Comment: I doubt anything with a VGA socket has high refresh rates or resolutions. You can squeeze 2k over VGA… but you wouldn't want to.